# After writing to excel file using win32, the file does not load

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am using `win32com` to write pretty big dataframes (2 dataframes of ~170k rows * 15 columns) to already existing Excel files. I am using this library as I find that `openpyxl` overwrites pivot tables and charts in an existing Excel file, which I need to maintain. Having looked at other questions on this site, about writing to existing excel files while maintaining existing pivot tables and charts within the file, it appears the `win32com` is most recommended. But I haven't come across a question about its utility when dealing with large amounts of data.

My code is as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = False

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C://Documents/Data_file.xlsx")
xlSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
StartRow = 2
StartCol = 2

##Dataframe contains 170k rows and 15 columns. I do this same thing with 
##another similar dataframe and into another sheet in the same Excel file

##Creating a an arbitrary dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(170000, 15)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'))
##Converting dataframe into an acceptable format for win32
xT1 = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
LastRow = StartRow + len(xT1) - 1 # Number of records
LastCol =  StartCol + len(xT1[0]) - 1        # Number of columns
xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), xlSheet.Cells(LastRow , LastCol)).Value = xT1  # Writing to the excel sheet 
wb.Close(True) 
xl.Quit() 

##Do the same as above, with another dataframe of similar size to the one before, but write to a different Sheet

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C://Documents/Data_file.xlsx")
xlSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    
StartRow = 3
StartCol = 3

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(170000, 15)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'))
##Converting dataframe into an acceptable format for win32
xT2 = [tuple(x) for x in df_2.values]
LastRow = StartRow + len(xT2) - 1 # Number of records
LastCol =  StartCol + len(xT2[0]) - 1        # Number of columns
xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), xlSheet.Cells(LastRow , LastCol)).Value = xT2  # Writing to the excel sheet 
wb.Close(True) 
xl.Quit()
```

The code runs without error and the Excel files Date modified is updated. However, when I open the file "Data_file", its unusable. The loading wheel keeps spinning and Im unable to do anything with the file. Is this a common issue when writing a lot of data using this module? And is there a better way to do this (either using the same module, or using another module altogether)?

Comment: Is this a programming question or an Excel question? Can you provide a [mre], please, so everyone can generate an Excel file for himself?

Comment: @ThomasWeller It is a question about how to best write dataframes with large amounts of data to existing excel files without disrupting Pivot tables and graphs within the file. Specifically, from other questions about the topic, it seems like win32com is a useful library to do so, but for my case, with huge dataframes, it appears that the updated excel file cannot be used. Once opened, all I see is a spinning wheel and basically can't do anything with it. So, I want to understand if this is a common issue and if there might be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: "t appears that the updated excel file cannot be used." - I'd like to try that on my machine with 96G RAM, so I'd like a [mre] which generates 170k*15 cells, e.g. of random data

Comment: @ThomasWeller Understood. I edited the question with a similar dataframe. The dataframe I use contains dates as well, which I imagine shouldnt make a difference. Please let me know if this is okay. Im happy to make further edits for reproducibility.

Comment: The file created by the given code loads in 4 seconds on my machine and uses only 600 MB of memory

Comment: @ThomasWeller When 2 dataframes are written into the same Excel file? I dont understand what the issue might be then on my end.

Comment: 8 seconds with 2 sheets. I'm using Excel 2013. Maybe you can try [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out what Excel does